# Collections.shuffle only working once

Tags: java, collections, random, shuffle

I checked a previous answer but it didn't work for me.

I have the following code

```
public static void createPopulation(ArrayList<City> city)
{
    for (int i = 0; i<gen.getSize(); i++)   {   
        ArrayList<City> copy = new ArrayList<City> (city); //added from previous question
        Collections.shuffle(copy, new Random(seed));
        gen.add(copy);
    }
}
```

It shuffles once, with or without the line with the comment on it, but doesn't shuffle again. It's a GP algorithim (well, the start of it) where I have to shuffle the members of a population.

Comment: What is `seed`?  When you create a new `Random` from the same seed value it will give you the same sequence of "random" numbers every time.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That's because you recreate the `Random` object.

Do this :

```
Random r = new Random(seed);
for (int i = 0; i<gen.getSize(); i++)   {   
    ArrayList<City> copy = new ArrayList<City> (city); //added from previous question
    Collections.shuffle(copy, r);
    gen.add(copy);
}
```

From [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Random.html) :

> If two instances of Random are created with the same seed, and the
>   same sequence of method calls is made for each, they will generate and
>   return identical sequences of numbers.

An instance of `Random` is a generator whose state is changed each time you call a random function on it. Here you don't want to reset this state to the initial seed based one, because that would lead to the same sequence of returned numbers. That's why you don't want to recreate a new instance for each shuffling.

Comment: Are you saying that they should reuse the `Random` object or that the problem is that they're (essentially) doing so? I feel like I must be being stupid and missing something, but your code seems to me like it would result in exactly the same as the code in the question.

Comment: I edited because it was poorly worded. `shuffle` calls random functions, if you recreate for each shuffle the same Random object, then you do the exact same sequence of operations each time. If you initialize the object only once, the sequence of operation doesn't restart and the results are different. The important point to understand is that the Random instance (generator) has a state and that calling any random function on it changes this state.